# How many connections are using my exit node?

Tags: exit-relays, circuit

I am running Tor as an exit node on Ubuntu. Is it possible to know the number of connections to my exit node at the current time?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, and thank you for running an exit! Netstat, lsof, and other connection resolvers can tell you the number of active connections a process is making. [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) also has a [module](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/east_of_the_sun.html) to make this easy.

Tor has a feature to prevent debuggers like gdb from analyzing tor's memory. This feature inadvertently breaks connection resolvers like the above, so you'll need to add `DisableDebuggerAttachment 0` to your torrc. After that getting the count is easy. In the following case 29124 is my tor pid.

```
> % netstat -np | grep "29124/tor" | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

Be careful about looking at specific connection information. Counts would be fine, but looking at exit destinations would be eavesdropping (... and possibly illegal due to wiretap laws).

Comment: Thanks Damian for your reply. i think the number which shows after running the command "% netstat -np | grep "29124/tor" | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l" is the number of connections of my exit node to the web server. Am I correct? I also want to know the number of circuits through my node i.e. guard->middle->my exit node. Is it possible? @Damian

Comment: if I would run my relay as middle node i.e neither exit nor guard, then how would I find the number of circuits through my OR?

Comment: If you're interested in that sort of information then I'd suggest taking a peek at arm. It has a connection panel that can show you this sort of information: https://www.atagar.com/arm/

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do with arm?

Comment: Download arm, and read its 'README' document.